# Are treatments for (hyper/hypo)parathyroidism mutually exclusive from treatmeants to (hyper/hypo)calcemia?

Tags: medications, treatment, endocrinology, thyroid, calcium

Summarized in the table below the drugs that were listed in my professor's lecture slides for the treatment of Hyperparathyroidism (first column) and hypoparathyroidism (second column)

[image]

- Are treatments for (hyper/hypo)parathyroidism mutually exclusive from treatmeants to (hyper/hypo)calcemia?

  - That is, I have to decide whether I am willing to treat the calcium disorder or the parathyroid disorder, but I can't target both at the same time, is this correct?
  - While studying, I thought that if, for example, we were to treat hyperparathyroidism by giving cincalcet (which lowers PTH), and then we decide to give Furosemide (which lowers calcium).
  - Wouldn’t that be arbitrary and pointless? especially that if we lower calcium by furosemide then we are inducing hypocalcemia which would stimulate PTH release all over again.

    - My point is, we can’t use Furosemide to treat hyperparathyroidism, but we can use it to treat hypercalcemia provided that no PTH-lowering drugs were used.
  - In the same vein, using teriparatide (↑PTH) and thiazide diuretics (↑Ca) simultaneously would counteract the efforts towards treating hypoparathyroidism and culminate in lowering PTH all over again. Am I right?

Attached below are the original lecture slides, for your reference
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 dislike on the Q seems to be right as no research effort has been put but still assuming being a student having doubts and and is still in theory stage (inexperienced) i would try to answer.

Your questions seems to be flawed as you are not taking into account what is the cause of hyper/hypo states

1. e.g.in hypo-parathyroidism if the cause is surgical excision of glands then shouldnt, we treat the both the cause and effect i.e. treat the hypoparathyroid state with teriparatide (rPTH) and effect of hypoparathyroidism specifically hypocalcemia using calcium supplements, thiazides conserving calcium by decreasing excretion, and using Vit D which has effects at mutiple levels
2. similary in hyperparathyroid state if the cause of hypercalcemia is an adenoma then shouldn't we treat the functional adenoma and its effects - that is treat the hyperparathyroidism by giving cinalcet and treat the effect hypercalemia by causing excretion using furosemide.

Hope this clarifies. This answer is targetted at UG level because beyond that guidelines based on severity of states would be better to answer. what to use in which situation.

Comment: While I agree that this is essentially correct, you should support the answer with a source or two, otherwise why trust it? Also, the wording - which might be a language issue - is a bit odd. Might you have used AI to help answer the question? Apologies if I offend.

Comment: Your answered clarified it so much, especially the part where you say that we have to treat the disorder *and its effects*. This addressed my doubts directly. So thank you so much and many apologies if my question sounded naive compared to the questions on this website.

Comment: @anongoodnurse you very right, something anybody said or writes as answer should be verified; but as it is sort of discussion group, hence i posted without any specific reference. but on other level the nature of question was similar to what i went and pondered over during me UG course so i could resonate quickly.

Comment: Also what i feel In other dimension the medical literature like books, articles , guidelines & practice standards usually do not provide background reasoning of any such sort; instead simply mention that it is level 5 or 4 or any such level of evidence, Questions like this are best handled in classroom or with peer. I would try to find the exact reference if possible.

Comment: @DoePull Glad i helped; and no question is naive or stupid it is just the perspective of the answer-er or interpreter. continue asking questions how stupid they may feel.

Comment: @Sage - This isn't a discussion board; it's a Q&A site with the goal of authoritative answers for (researched) questions. I would not be surprised if it gets a post notice for lack of sources, even if it is accurate. Also, which textbooks don't have a list of supporting sources at the end of each chapter? Which journal articles don't support their statements? You are in error; even Cochrane papers have links.

Comment: @anongoodnurse okiee this discussion can on as u see & 2nd u misunderstood where i said about dimension the medical literature; but let's put my point => open williams endocrinology textbook find the chapter of parathyroid disorders - In 16E it would be Chapter 28 titled " Hormones & Disorders of Mineral Metabolism" cont.

Comment: Now search your query in headings body text. u may reach a conclusion as dedutive reasoning but to find the exact answer to specific problem would not be possible because textbook description is not in Q&A form it would epidemiology, pathogenesis and hence. i summed my generalization to medical literature. In the present context i feel the right answer would infact be chapter 3 principles of hormone action and there also no there would reference to one of the many endocrine systems but not all. so u have go to chapter 28 but there is no generalization which is chapter 3. so u see loop. cont.

Comment: so you are right but i don't mind if the end result is reached, but on my personal level (if i had been the ans seeker) i would not have agreed with answerer till i got the pinpoint reference to the answer. in this case the nature of question was deductive reasoning of the facts (the real reference was already in the presentation slides of the lecturer); so i did not find necessary to cite my own reference; hope i clarify my position.

Comment: Finally it would difficult to do full SYSTEMATIC REVIEWS" if this is expected sort of verification of every Q&A; would be more appropriate for answerer to answer based on current knowledge. as pointing towards more references. would be better for me to browse the site and but not indulge in these discussions for proving oneself; so thank you i got the lesson on day 1 of joining. Thank You.

Comment: @Sage - medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/169. "...but not indulge in these discussions for proving oneself..." How is anyone to learn the 'culture' of a site if no one explains it? The very best way is to take the tour and read the help section, but not many people are so inclined (believe it or not, I did do so on my first SE site. I like understanding the playing field.)

Comment: Nobody here is expecting a full systematic review, but we do expect that you support your answer with at least one authoritative reference. You said above, "open williams endocrinology textbook find the chapter of parathyroid disorders - In 16E it would be Chapter 28 titled 'Hormones & Disorders of Mineral Metabolism'". That would suffice if you actually [edit] your question and add it, but things you say in comments don't matter. So your choice. Your answer may be deleted if you leave it as is.